# syntax error when trying to query json documents in postgresql

Tags: json, database, postgresql

on my postgresql 9.6, I ran into an error with a table created like

```
create table jsonTest (id integer, data jsonb);
```

The table has the following data:

```
select * from jsonTest;
 id |               data               
----+----------------------------------
  1 | {"tags": ["AA", "BB", "CC"]}
  2 | {"tags": ["BB", "DD"]}
  2 | {"tags": ["CC"]}
  4 | {"city": "austin", "tags": "EE"}
(4 rows)
```

But when I tried to select, got syntax error:

```
template1=# select * from jsonTest where data->>city = 'austin';
ERROR:  column "city" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from jsonTest where data->>city = 'austin';
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `data->>'city'`

Comment: Thank you @klin! It appears to be a common mistake for someone who used javascript a lot.   Please write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The right operand](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)  of `->>` operator for JSON object is `text`. Use the apostrophes for the key, because without them Postgres interprets the name as an identifier (a column name):

```
data->>'city'
```